# Почему андроид коверкает цвета?

Tags: color, android, графика

Проблема следующая. Грузится картинка, (неважно как, через imageview, drawbitmap - одно и тоже) но при этом её цвета немного другие. Даже если просто указать фон с помощью color, всё равно цвета немного другие. Возможно проблема конечно в фотошопе (в чём я сомневаюсь). НО точно не в восприятии )

Comment: а Вы попробуйте взять ещё пару разных мониторов, на принтере распечатать. И увидите, что цвета немножко различаются.

Comment: все дело в матрице дисплея ;)   
У разных типов несколько разная цветопередача.   
И считается, что tft наиболее точно передает цвета, а вот amoled наобород, делает все более насыщенным.

Comment: Дык на эмуляторе же запускал! Да и грузил саму картинку на телефон и сравнивал с приложением - не дурак, прекрасно понимаю что есть сотни разных экранов.

Comment: тут тоже все может быть не так просто. Во первых, эмулятор может использовать 16 битную модель 565, тогда когда декстоп в целом - 32битный ARGB. И если у Вас зоркий глаз дизайнера, то да, цвета испортятся. К тому же, никто не запрещает эмулятору применять свою цветовую модель.

На выставке в Барселоне показывали телефон с eInk экраном. Вот там цвета искажаются:)

Comment: Проблема в фотошопе(а именно, в цветовом профиле)

Comment: Вот это уже очень похоже на правду )
А по поводу цветовых профилей можно ли подробней?